# About expressions on while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, post-increment, postfix-operator

Assume i > 0 is true.
Why is this expression:

```
while(i > 0) {
  printf("Hello \n);
  i--;
};
```

equal to this expression:

```
 while(i--) {
  printf("Hello \n");
};
```

Comment: It's actually not equivalent if `i` is less than zero at the beginning

Comment: @UnholySheep you are right, i forgot to initialize i, let me fix that

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this is not an expression. It's a `while` loop. Also, they're not equal. `while(i--)` is equivalent to `while(i-- != 0)`, which checks for *inequality*, not *greater than*.

If `i` is greater or equal than `0` in the beginning, both snippets will behave the same way.

Answer (score -1):

It is evident that you mean the equivalence of the loop executions. They are equivalent due to the fact that the variable `i` is not used in the body of the loop and provided that `i` is a positive number.

However the loops logically look the following way

```
while(i > 0) {
  printf("Hello \n);
  i--;
};
```

and

```
while( int temp = i; i -= 1; temp > 0 ) {
  printf("Hello \n");
};
```

Though the second construction of the while loop is not valid but it shows that the variable `i` will be changed in any case whether when the condition is false or before each iteration of the loop.

Consider the following demonstrative program and its output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 1;

    puts( "The first loop" );
    while ( i > 0 ) 
    {
        printf("%d: Hello\n", i );
        i--;
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    i = 1;

    puts( "The second loop" );
    while ( i-- ) 
    {
        printf("%d: Hello\n", i );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    i = 0;

    while ( i > 0 ) 
    {
        printf("%d: Hello\n", i );
        i--;
    }

    printf( "After the first loop i = %d\n", i );

    putchar( '\n' );

    i = 0;

    while ( i-- ) 
    {
        printf("%d: Hello\n", i );
        i--;
    }

    printf( "After the second loop i = %d\n", i );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The first loop
1: Hello

The second loop
0: Hello

After the first loop i = 0

After the second loop i = -1
```

Take into account that in the condition of the first loop there is checked whether the variable `i` is greater than 0 while in the condition of the second loop there is checked whether the variable `i` is not equal to 0. So the conditions for entering the bodies of the loop are different.

If `i` has an unsigned integer type or it is guaranteed that `i` can not be negative then the following loops would be fully equivalent

```
while(i > 0) {
  printf("Hello \n);
  i--;
};
```

and

```
while(i != 0) {
  printf("Hello \n);
  i--;
};
```